# Copying a file to a different folder and renaming it with the current date

Tags: file-io, copy, applescript

I am trying to recreate a VBScript that I wrote that would copy a file to a remote volume then rename the file with the current date. There's a bunch of Google (and SO) results for this, but I can't seem to get it quiet right. What I have is below, but when I run it, it returns `error "Finder got an error: Handler can’t handle objects of this class."` on the duplicate command.

```
set {month:mm} to (current date)
set {day:d} to (current date)
set {year:y} to (current date)
set theDate to mm & "-" & d & "-" & y
set fileName to theDate & ".xml"


tell application "Finder"
    duplicate POSIX file "/Users/RHPT/Documents/File.xml" to POSIX file "/Volumes/Public/Backup"
    set name of POSIX file ("/Volumes/Public/Backup/File.xml" as alias) to fileName
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
set {month:mm, day:d, year:y} to (current date)
set theDate to mm & "-" & d & "-" & y as text
set fileName to theDate & ".xml"

tell application "Finder"
    set dupeFile to duplicate POSIX file "/Users/RHPT/Documents/File.xml" to POSIX file "/Volumes/Public/Backup"
    set dupeFile's name to fileName
end tell
```

EDIT

```
set {month:mm, day:d, year:y} to (current date)
set theDate to mm & "-" & d & "-" & y as text
set fileName to theDate & ".xml"

set sourceFile to POSIX file "/Users/RHPT/Documents/File.xml"
set destFolder to POSIX file "/Volumes/Public/Backup"

tell application "Finder"
    set dupeFile to duplicate sourceFile to destFolder
    set dupeFile's name to fileName
end tell
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the posix file command outside of the Finder block?

Answer (score 0):

Using do shell scripts can also be useful.

```
set theFile to "/Users/RHPT/Documents/File.xml"
set backUpPath to "/Volumes/Public/Backup"
set theDate to (do shell script "date "date '+%m-%d-%Y'")
do shell script "cp " & quoted form of theFile & space & quoted form of backUpPath & theDate & ".xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your script.

One way to debug is to put a return statement in there and see what you’ve created so far. When you run your script, it will stop at the return statement and you’ll see what you’ve returned in the Result pane at the bottom of the AppleScript Editor window. Like so:

```
set {month:mm} to (current date)
set {day:d} to (current date)
set {year:y} to (current date)
set theDate to mm & "-" & d & "-" & y
set fileName to theDate & ".xml"
return fileName -- debugging line, remove after debugging
-- returns: {August, "-", 7, "-", 2014, ".xml"}
```

So what you have in “theDate” variable is a list, and what you are doing after “set fileName …” is adding an item to the end of that list. What you want in those variables is text. So where you are building “theDate“ variable, append “as text” to that line:

```
set {month:mm} to (current date)
set {day:d} to (current date)
set {year:y} to (current date)
set theDate to mm & "-" & d & "-" & y as text
set fileName to theDate & ".xml"
return fileName -- debugging line, remove after debugging
-- returns: "August-7-2014.xml"
```

Now, in the “set fileName …” line you are concatenating 2 strings of text, and you have a text filename that you can use later.

Of course, now that you’ve debugged the above part of the script, you can take out the “return fileName” statement so that your script continues on to the next line:

```
duplicate POSIX file "/Users/RHPT/Documents/File.xml" to POSIX file "/Volumes/Public/Backup"
```

Since you want to work with the duplicated file later (to change its name) you should set the result of the duplicate command to a variable:

```
set theDuplicatedFile to duplicate POSIX file "/Users/RHPT/Documents/File.xml" to POSIX file "/Volumes/Public/Backup"
```

Also, you shouldn’t hard-code the path to your documents folder. There is a special property for that — “the path to the documents folder” — which will enable your script to work for any user — not just users with home folders named “RHPT” — or for you in the future if your username changes on your next Mac. So add the following 2 lines to your variable declarations, and also a debugging return statement to see what your POSIX path looks like:

```
set theDocumentsFolderPath to the path to the documents folder as text
set theDocumentsFolderPOSIXPath to the POSIX path of theDocumentsFolderPath
return theDocumentsFolderPOSIXPath -- debugging line, remove after debugging
-- returns: "/Users/RHPT/Documents/"
```

But the thing is, the POSIX path is not going to do you much good, because the “duplicate” command requires an alias object. You don’t have to think in paths when working with Finder, because this is not bash or MS-DOS — the Mac works in objects. So what you really want is this:

```
set theDocumentsFolder to the path to the documents folder as alias
return theDocumentsFolder -- debugging line, remove after debugging
-- returns: alias "Macintosh HD:Users:RHPT:Documents:"
```

And then the above “duplicate …” line becomes this:

```
set theDuplicatedFile to duplicate file "File.xml" of theDocumentsFolder to POSIX file "/Volumes/Public/Backup"
```

… but there are still more problems with the “duplicate” line.

This:

```
to POSIX file "/Volumes/Public/Backup"
```

… is not a POSIX file. It’s a folder path. You want the duplicated file to go into the folder “Backup” of the disk “Public,” right? You can just ask Finder for that in plain English:

```
set theDuplicatedFile to duplicate file "File.xml" of theDocumentsFolder to the folder "Backup" of the disk "Public"
```

… and you should probably tell Finder not to replace the file if it already exists, just in case:

```
set theDuplicatedFile to duplicate file "File.xml" of theDocumentsFolder to the folder "Backup" of the disk "Public" replacing no
```

And then your final line:

```
set name of POSIX file ("/Volumes/Public/Backup/File.xml" as alias) to fileName
```

… becomes:

```
set the name of theDuplicatedFile to fileName
```

And your entire script looks like this:

```
set {month:mm} to (current date)
set {day:d} to (current date)
set {year:y} to (current date)
set theDate to mm & "-" & d & "-" & y as text
set fileName to theDate & ".xml"
set theDocumentsFolder to the path to the documents folder as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set theDuplicatedFile to duplicate file "File.xml" of theDocumentsFolder to the folder "Backup" of the disk "Public" replacing no
    set the name of theDuplicatedFile to fileName
end tell
```

You can also optimize your script a little bit. You are getting the “current date” object 3 times, when you only need to get it once, which will take one-third of the time:

```
set theCurrentDate to the current date
set {month:mm} to theCurrentDate
set {day:d} to theCurrentDate
set {year:y} to theCurrentDate
```

And you can optionally rewrite your script a little bit for readability, because a key feature of AppleScript is that it is readable as plain English, even for people who don’t know how to write it:

```
set theCurrentDate to the current date
set theMonth to the month of theCurrentDate
set theDay to the day of theCurrentDate
set theYear to the year of theCurrentDate
set theFileNameDate to theMonth & "-" & theDay & "-" & theYear as text
set theDuplicatedFileName to theFileNameDate & ".xml"
set theDocumentsFolder to the path to the documents folder as alias

tell application "Finder"
    set theDuplicatedFile to duplicate file "File.xml" of theDocumentsFolder to the folder "Backup" of the disk "Public" replacing no
    set the name of theDuplicatedFile to theDuplicatedFileName
end tell
```

Finally, unless you are an expert bash user, I recommend against doing simple stuff like this with shell scripts. Ideally, you wouldn’t use the “do shell script” command to do things that Finder can do for you in a much safer way. Use the “do shell script” command to get at unique features of the UNIX layer, like running a PHP function or a Perl script. The best app on your Mac for copying and renaming files between HFS+ disks is Finder.